# Matlab linprog yields an unbounded result to a bounded model

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

```
clear
A=[-1 0 -1 0; 0 -1 0 -1; 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1];
b=[-50 -70 80 45];
f=[0.5; 0.6; 0.4; 0.55];
options = optimoptions('linprog','Algorithm','dual-simplex');
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],[],[],options);
```

Code shown above produces an unbounded result `Problem is unbounded` where Lindo and Excel Solver find the optimal objective function value which is 62.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i run this:

```
clear
A=[-1 0 -1 0; 0 -1 0 -1; 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1];
b=[-50 -70 80 45];
f=[0.5; 0.6; 0.4; 0.55];
options = optimoptions('linprog','Algorithm','simplex','display','iter');
x0=[0 0 0 0]'
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],[],[],x0,options);
```

I get:

```
Phase 1: Compute initial basic feasible point.
      Iter            Infeasibility
       0                      120
       1                       70
       2                       40
       3                       -0

Phase 2: Minimize using simplex.
      Iter            Objective              Dual Infeasibility 
                        f'*x                   A'*y+z-w-f
       0                   63                    0.111803
       1                 62.5                        0.05
Exiting: The problem is unbounded; the constraints are not restrictive enough.
```

Same solution as you mentioned.

But nothing prevent from the solver increase x

Answer (score 1):

**That's correct behaviour** taken into account what matlab's `linprog` is doing.

The reason for this observation is the following:

- `linprog` assumes variables are **free** ((-inf,inf) if no bound is given) like in your case

**Your solution (observed with Lindo) is the one, where your solution-vector is constrained to be nonnegative**.

This can be expressed through constraints or using bounds. The docs give the following example:

```
Example: To specify that all x-components are positive, lb = zeros(size(f))
    # personal opinion: this should be called "nonnegative"
```

I'm not a Matlab user but using my tools, i can verify that:

- the problem without the nonnegativity-constraint / or bounds expressing the same is unbounded
- the problem with the constraint / bounds has a solution of **62.5**

**Remark:** Many mathematical-programming frameworks / solvers assume that the solution-vector is nonnegative by default, which is different from what `linprog` is doing. The former is a consequence of the underlying algorithmic theory.